# ¿Se puede insertar un If adentro de una variable concatenada en PHP?

Tags: php, html

La condicional es para mostrar adentro del bucle si el usuario es director mostrar ese boton.

El mensaje de error es "Unexpected } expected ;"

```
while($fila = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $salida.="<table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                     <td scope='row'><a href='editar.php?codigo=".$fila['ID']."' class='btn btn-success'><i class='text-light me-1 bi bi-pencil-square'></i> Editar</a></td>
                <td scope='row' >
                 "if($usuario == 'Director'){"
                  <a OnClick=\"return confirm('¿Estás seguro de eliminar ?');\" href='eliminar.php?codigo=".$fila['ID']."' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='text-light  bi bi-trash-fill'></i> Eliminar</a>
                  "}"
                </td>
                  </tr>";
    }

    $salida.="</tbody></table>";
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se puede lo que quieres, pero te estas complicando mucho, para eso son las variables. Puedes usar un bloque `if/else` para generar una variable con el html que deseas:

```
if($usuario == 'Director'){
    $boton = "-- aqui va el HTML del boton --";
} else {
    $boton = "";
}
```

O, si es un `if/else` sencillo, es común hacerlo de la forma ternaria:

```
$boton = ($usuario == 'Director') ? "-- aqui va el HTML del boton --" : "";
```

Por otro lado te aconsejo que no dibujes etiquetas de apertura HTML dentro de un un condicional si el cierre respectivo está afuera (también al contrario), como el caso de las etiquetas `<table>` y `<tbody>`. Si tu base de datos devuelve 0 resultados, entonces no va a entrar al `while()`, pero más abajo dice que dibuje un `</tbody></table>` que no coincidirá con ninguna etiqueta de apertura.

```
<?php
// ...
$salida = "<table><thead>
    <tr><th>Titulo de Col1</th><th>Titulo de Col2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";
while($fila = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $boton = ($usuario == 'Director') ? "-- aqui va el HTML del boton --" : "";
    $salida.="
        <tr>
            <td scope='row'><a href='editar.php?codigo=".$fila['ID']."' class='btn btn-success'><i class='text-light me-1 bi bi-pencil-square'></i> Editar</a></td>
            <td scope='row'>$boton</td>
        </tr>";
}
$salida.="</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Si tienes razón, me falta practica en la lógica, la voy a mejorar, confirme a las etiquetas de apertura ya las saque del bucle, muchas gracias por tu respuesta es la solución (:

Comment: Hice una corrección con las etiquetas `thead` (que las puedes omitir si no las vas a usar) y `tbody` @Oren . Saludos!